# Run multiple firestore batch.commit()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a web app where a user can create multiple firestore documents via a form input. I'm using batch.commit() successfully to add those objects to a collection.

```
             arrayOfObjectsFromForm.forEach((object) => {
                var docRef = db.collection("CollectionName").doc();
                batch.set(docRef, object);
             })

            await batch.commit().then(() => {
                console.log("committed batch write to firestore!")
                return alert("success")
            });
```

However, after the successful batch.commit() if the user fills out the form again to create another set of documents to write, there will be an error: *A write batch can no longer be used after commit() has been called.* Is there a way to call batch.commit() multiple times in a row? I thought returning a value after the batch.commit() would "clean up" the function to use it again but get the error still.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're reusing the same `batch` object that you already committed, which is indeed not allowed.

You'll need to create a new batch object once the initial one is committed.

So something like:

```
batch.commit();
batch = null;
```

So that you can then check whether you need to create a new batch upon the form submission:

```
if (batch == null) {
  batch = db.batch();
}
... add item to batch
```

Comment: yep resetting is all I had to do! Thanks!

Comment: @colinwymore hit the tick button if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

Final solution is pretty simple

```
   var batch = db.batch() //use to write multiple documents

   arrayOfObjectsFromTheForm.forEach((object) => {
      var docRef = db.collection("CollectionName").doc();
      batch.set(docRef, object);
   })

   await batch.commit().then(() => {
      console.log("committed batch write to firestore!")
      //reset batch so it can be used again
      batch = db.batch() 
      return alert("success")
   });
```

Comment: Since this is pretty much the solution I posted, it is not custom to post it as an alternative solution. Also note that you have a race condition in there, as the `then()` will only be called once the batch completes on the server, and there may be environments that allow forms to be submitted while between when you call `commit()` and when your `then()` executes. If you keep it in `then()` (and risk the race condition), you should also put the new batch in `catch()` is my feeling.